# How can I UNION two arrays in JSONNET?

Tags: jsonnet

If I have two arrays, for example,

```
local array1 = [0,6,12];
local array2 = std.range(10,15);
```

and I want an array `[0,6,10,11,12,13,14,15]` (not concerned specifically about ordering of the elements, just don't want duplicates)

How can I perform this as a union operation that will work for any two arrays of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

JSonnet has the function `std.setUnion` for this use-case. Your result can be found with:

```
local result = std.setUnion(array1, array2);
```

See the [JSonnet Standard Library reference](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html) for more details.